# Why is Geth.exe flagged by Malwarebytes as malicious?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I installed Mist to setup an ETH wallet. Mist comes packaged with geth.exe, but when starting the application it attempts to connect to 95.79.46.241:30303 which gets flagged by Malwarebytes. An IP lookup of that address reveals it is registered to a holding company in Russia. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P2P connections are setup to synchronize your local blockchain. You need to configure Malwarebytes to exclude Mist/Geth.

[image]

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question but why that particular address/port? What directs it to make that initial connection? thanks

Comment: It's going to block most (if not all) peer connections it tries to establish. The way blockchains are sync'ed would be considered suspicious behavior by any malware detection app.